# My Angular JS view won't update with value set in service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been stuck on something for hours already and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I'm building an authentication service but I'll strip it down as much as I can for this question.

So I have links, login & logout in the view as such in my view:

View

```
<a href="javascript:;" ng-if="!loggedIn" ng-click="login()">Login</a>
<a href="javascript:;" ng-if="loggedIn" ng-click="logout()">Logout</a>
```

When I login, $scope.loggedIn changes correctly to true but when I logout it doesn't switch back to false and therefore my view isn't updated.

Could anyone shed any light on why this is happening? I can't figure out why it's working for login but not for logout.

My factory

```
 app.factory('authService', ['Session', function(Session) {
     var userAuth = {
         loginFB: function() {
            // some code that logs the user in, this works fine

            Session.create();
         },
         logoutFB: function() {
            // some code that logs the user out, this works fine

            Session.destroy();
         }
     }
     return userAuth;
 }]);
```

My service

```
app.service('Session', function() {

    this.logInActive = false;

    this.create = function() {

        this.logInActive = true;
        console.log("created");
    }

    this.destroy = function() {

        this.logInActive = false;
        console.log("destroyed");
    }

});
```

My global controller

```
app.controller("globalcontroller", ['$scope', 
                                    'Session', 
                                    'authService',
                                    function($scope, Session, authService) {

    $scope.loggedIn = false;

    $scope.login = function() {

        authService.loginFB();
    };

    $scope.logout = function() {

        authService.logoutFB();
    };

    $scope.$watch(function() {
        $scope.loggedIn = Session.logInActive;
    });
}]);
```

Comment: Can't you just set $scope.loggedIn = false in the $scope.logout function?

Comment: @Rob - sorry I guess this was a downfall of stripping down my code, I can't set it there in case there's an issue logging the user out in the authService and they actually remain logged in. I mean, it'd work, but I'm looking for something a bit more robust in this case. Thanks.

Comment: I think you've stripped it down too much to see where the issue lies. Here's a plunker, your code works as-is: http://plnkr.co/edit/Rbt9plSJi4QB4jD6qiMR

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the service is returning but assuming your returning a promise after destroying the session, in your controller:

```
$scope.logout = function() {
    authService.logoutFB().success(function() {
        $scope.isLoggedIn = false;
    });
}
```